# String inside function

Tags: php

I have Written a program in which you have to create a function. The function will expect 3 parameters $string, $start, $end. Inside the function, you have to write the logic inside the function to automatically print the string depending upon the value of $start and $end.

I tried this Whole function is working correctly but the array length is 55 but when i specify $end=55 then it returns the error Ending Value Exceeded String length:

```
function string_function($string,$start,$end){

    $length= strlen($string);

    if($start<0 || $end<0){
        echo "Start or end of string cannot be in negative";    
    }else if($start>$length || $end>$length){
        echo "Entered values exceed more than String's Length";
    }else if($start>$end){
        echo "Start point is greater than end point, Which is Invalid";
    }else if($end<$length){
        $length <= ($end+1);
        for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
            echo "[$i] => ".$string[$i]."<br>";
        }
        }else{

            echo "Ending Value Exceeded String length";
    }
}
$start = 22;
$end =54;
$string = "I am a programmer and i am passionate about programming";
string_function($string, $start, $end);
```

Help would be welcomed.

Comment: Yes `55<55` is false. Change your `else if($end<$length)` to `else if($end<=$length)`

Comment: Now this error came and this error is very fraustating for me
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 55 in J:\xampp\htdocs\tasks\task5\correction.php on line 57
[55] =>

Comment: Array index starts at 0, so your array has `$string[0]` to `$string[54]`

Comment: Yes i knew that. But how to restrict this so that it does not appear in the output and display error message instead;

Comment: Change `$i<=$end` to `$i<$end`

Comment: Added as an answer with short explanation. Consider marking it if it answered your query

Answer (score 0):

Change your else if part to:

```
else if($end<=$length){
    $length <= ($end+1);
    for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i++){
        echo "[$i] => ".$string[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Since your array starts from 0th index, so the end that you specify is length of the array. But the maximum array index is 1 less than the total length. Your iteration should therefore be 1 less than your `end` variable

*[As discussed in comments]*

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change '<' to '<=' when you compare $end and $lenght.